# Question about congruence

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Find the smallest positive n that satisfies the system of congruences

$$n \equiv 3 \pmod 4$$
$$n \equiv 4 \pmod5$$
$$n \equiv 5 \pmod 7$$

Approach: Not very useful

$4|3-n$, $5|4-n$, $7|5-n$

$3-n=4k$, $4-n=5t$, $5-n=7x$
set $3-n=t$, $4-n=t+1$, $5-n=t+2$

$t*(t+1)*(t+2)=140p$ then I would have to solve for t which would take me nowhere.

Comment: sorry, the last one is mod 7

Comment: Have you heard of the [chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem)?

Comment: No, not yet. That's abstract algebra right?

Comment: With the change,  the simple approach I mentioned will not work. But the first two congruences can be rewritten as $x\equiv -1\pmod{4}$, $x\equiv --1\pmod{5}$, $x\equiv 5\pmod{7}$. The first two congruences have the solution $x\equiv -1\pmod{20}$. Now combine with $x\equiv 5\pmod{7}$.

Comment: It can be stated in terms of abstract algebra, but it's about modular arithmethic, no abstract algebra needed.

Comment: I am in elementary number theory. I haven't seen the chinese remainder theorem yet.

Comment: You should take a look, it's precisely what this question is about!

Comment: Yeah, for the examples I see, I can tell it's exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't know Chinese Remainder Theorem then one possible way of doing this  is

$4|n-3 \Rightarrow n=4k+3 \Rightarrow n \in \{3,7,11,15,19,...\}$

$5|n-4 \Rightarrow n=5s+4 \Rightarrow n \in \{4,9,14,19,...\}$

$7|n-5 \Rightarrow n=7t+5 \Rightarrow n \in \{5,12,19,...\}$

Now,your solution set will be the intersection of all the three sets obtained above as you want your solution to satisfy all the three conditions.

You can see smallest positive integer satisfying all conditions is $19$.

**NOTE: This method is not always feasible as you will not necessarily get a solution this easily as we had obtained above in $4-5$ steps.**

**Edit: Adding one more way to tackle this (as you were trying to approach this )**

$n \equiv3 ($mod$ 4) \Rightarrow n=4k+3\ \ \ ....(1)$

$n \equiv4($mod $5) \Rightarrow 4k+3 \equiv4($mod$ 5) \Rightarrow 4k \equiv1($mod$5)\Rightarrow k \equiv4($mod$5)\Rightarrow k=5s+4$

Substituting value of $k$ in $eq.(1) $ we get $n=20s+19\ \ \ ... (2)$

Now, $n \equiv5($mod$7) \Rightarrow20s+19 \equiv5($mod $7) \Rightarrow 20s  \equiv-14($mod$7) \Rightarrow s \equiv0($mod$7) \Rightarrow s=7t$

Substituting value of $s$ in $eq.(2) $ we get $n=140t+19$

And you get $19$ as your answer.

This method is more helpful than the last one.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $4$, $5$, and $7$ are coprime, so some complications are avoided in the following.

Three solutions below.  The first is very general.  The second can be very slow, especially if you are unlucky (which becomes overwhelmingly likely for larger versions of this type of problem).  The third can be done quickly, but shows very little mastery of the material...

What if you know of a number, $u_4$ congruent to $1 \pmod{4}$, $0 \pmod{5}$, and $0 \pmod{7}$ and similarly a $u_5$ and a $u_7$, similar to the standard basis for a vector space.  Then $3 u_4 + 4 u_5 + 5 u_7$ would be a number in the congruence class you are interested in.  (The first product is congruent to $3 \pmod{4}$, $0 \pmod{5}$, and $0 \pmod{7}$.  The other two products are also only have nonzero resides modulo the subscript of $u$.  So the sum has exactly the properties you want.)

Being congruent to $0$ $\pmod{5}$ and $\pmod{7}$ means being a multiple of $35$.  $35 \cong 3 \pmod{4}$, so we're not lucky.  $2 \cdot 35 = 70 \cong 2 \pmod{4}$ and $3 \cdot 35 = 105 \cong 1 \pmod{4}$, so $u_4 = 105$ works.  Similarly, $u_5$ is a multiple of $28 \cong 3 \pmod{5}$ and the sequence of residues of its multiples is $\{3, 6 \cong 1, \dots\}$ so $2 \cdot 28 = 56 = u_5$.  The sequence of multiples of $20$ modulo $7$ is $\{6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, \dots\}$ so $u_7 = 6 \cdot 20 = 120$.

Then $3\cdot 105 + 4 \cdot 56 + 5 \cdot 120 = 315 + 224 + 600 = 1139$ is such a number (but not necessarily the smallest positive one).

Check: (We use that $100$ is congruent to $0$, $0$, and $2$ modulo $4$, $5$, and $7$, respectively.)  \begin{align}
    1139 &\cong 0\cdot 11 + 39 \cong 3 \pmod{4}  \\
    1139 &\cong 0\cdot 11 + 39 \cong 4 \pmod{5}  \\
    1139 &\cong 2\cdot 11 + 39 \cong 5 \pmod{7}  \text{.}
\end{align}

Then $\mathrm{lcm}(4,5,7) = 4 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 = 140$, so there are only 140 different vectors of residues to these three moduli.  Therefore, we compute $1139 \cong 19 \pmod{140}$.  This is one less than a multiple of $4$ and of a multiple of $5$.  It is also $2$ less than a multiple of $7$.  It is the minimal positive such number.

There are other ways to do this.  The above is a general technique which is pretty fast for hand calculation.  Just counting up to 19 and checking each integer as you come to it is about as much work as the above for this problem.  Another way to go:

Find a $3 \pmod{4}$ that is congruent to $4 \pmod{5}$.  We write the elements of $3 \pmod{4}$ and mark the desired numbers with an asterisk:

```
3, 7, 11, 15, 19*, 23, 27, 31, 35, 39*, ...
```

These are congruent to $19 \pmod{4 \cdot 5 = 20}$.  Now find one of this subsequence that is also congruent to $5 \pmod{7}$, which happens immediately: $19$.  This can be a fast way to go.